# gdb execute through to a specific function

Tags: gdb

https://git.postgresql.org/cgit/postgresql.git/tree/src/test/modules/delay_execution/delay_execution.c
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967440/stepping-into-specific-function-in-gdb

I loaded the module delay_execution.
then `gdb -p $proc`
quite new to gdb. can I let gdb execute directly up to the beginning of delay_execution_planner?
there are many steps, press step by step seems not so good.

Comment: Rolled back the edit that added a new, separate question. Please don't ask new questions in an edit to an answered question, but open up a [new question post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what *breakpoints* are for.

A simple

```
break delay_execution_planner
continue
```

does what you need.

Comment: I have another newbie question.  see my update.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please don't ask new questions in an answered question post!! Ask a new question in a new post.. But beware that what you want is expensive, because there's probably a very large factor more function calls than you realize there are.